# Как принято именовать методы/функции в Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, чистый-код

Я придерживаюсь этих [рекомендации](https://habr.com/ru/articles/26077/) для winForms и wpf/uwp по написанию кода. Когда начал кодить web-app сложилось ощущение что для asp.net может быть принято именовать методы по-другому.
Если знаете статьи на тему требования и рекомендации по написанию кода для asp.net (как для верстки так и для бэка) можете, пожалуйста, поделиться?

Comment: То, что вы ищите, зовется Naming Conventions (Соглашения об именовании), все они прописаны в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) и относятся ко всем .NET проектам.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  я прошлась по ссылке, посмотрела, не увидела про Модель например. Когда создаем класс модель часто вижу, и сама тоже использую номинацию класса `SomeModel.cs` также для сервиса, но встретила там, что например для `Enum`  добавлять преффикс не следует, по вашему это так же относится и к модели и сервису ? то есть нужно ли преффиксы ставить к классам ?

Comment: @Dev18 Ну, слой модели это ведь не просто класс, который вы потом используете в контроллере или ViewModel слое, это еще и DTO/POCO и прочие классы ([MVVM документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm#model) "Examples of model objects include data transfer objects .."), которые отвечают за передачу данных. Относятся они к модели? Да. Можем добавить им приписку "Model"? Ну, будет странно) Поэтому, большинство проектов используют нечто такое: `Foo`, `FooViewMode`, `FooView` (аналог и для MVC).

Comment: @Dev18 Как пример MVVM проекта, могу дать [это](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/tree/master/samples/MvvmSample.Core/Models), это официальный пример от Microsoft по использованию их библиотеки CommunityToolkit, ну и как видите, модели без `...Model` в названии. Ну а вообще, не забывайте, что это набор рекомендации, а уже как вы там будете писать, зависит от вас и вашей команды, ведь именно команда устанавливает стиль своего кода. В одних командах приемлемо Model в названии, в других нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а почему там же в документации пишут не использовать [венгерскую нотацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) ведь грубо говоря это тот самый стиль устанавливаемый командой отсюда вопрос, стоит ли придерживаться команде не внедрять свои правила. И оч интересно, вы сами как обычно решаете как назвать сервис/модель//page

Comment: @Dev18 Нотация, это как по мне устаревший стиль, который использовался во времена написания кода в блокноте, без подсказок IDE и чего либо подобного. Вот она говорит, чтоб мы писали в начале тип, например `int Value` -> `int iValue`, задайте себе вопрос, оно нужно? Мне, нет, ибо я либо по значению вижу что это, либо просто наведу в студии и увижу тип. Если погулять по ссылкам вики, можно увидеть такое `Не используйте малопонятные префиксы или суффиксы (например, венгерскую нотацию), современные языки и средства разработки позволяют контролировать типы данных на этапе разработки и сборки`

Comment: @Dev18 `вы сами как обычно решаете` - я не веб разработчик, а десктоп (WPF в основном), в котором используется MVVM. Названия, как и сказал выше `Models/Person.cs`, `ViewModels/PersonViewModel.cs`, `Views/PersonView.cs/.xaml`. Если используется сервис, то `Services/PersonService.cs`. То есть, разделяю все по 
 папкам, которые в свою очередь являются `namespace`, имена описывают конкретный объект, с припиской того, к чему относятся (кроме Model, объяснил почему). Если пишется пример для SO, то в модели могу указать `...Model`, ибо так понятней читающим. Ну а так, все выше вроде сказал)

Answer (score 0):

Да нет, бегло пробежался по статье по ссылке, вроде всё для ASP.NET подходит и используется на практике на проектах, на которых принят стандартный майкрософтовский стайлгайд.
Единственный момент - не на всех проектах принят именно он, и отличия вполне могут быть связаны с этим.